# OpenCV:Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I get this type of error when I try to use the adaptiveThreshold() function. What could have gone wrong?

here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    try 
    {
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread("rubikscube.png");
        cv::Mat thres_final;
        cv::Mat adap_thres_final;

        cv::threshold(img, thres_final, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::adaptiveThreshold(img, adap_thres_final, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2);

        cv::namedWindow("Source");
        cv::imshow("Source", img);

        cv::namedWindow("Threshold");
        cv::imshow("Threshold", thres_final);

        cv::namedWindow("Adaptive Threshold");
        cv::imshow("Adaptive Threshold", adap_thres_final);

        cv::waitKey(0);

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception Occured! \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your image `CV_8UC1`?  The threshold methods only accept images that are single-channel unsigned 8-bit.  By default, OpenCV's `cv::imread` loads in the images in colour mode, meaning there are three channels.  Try doing this instead: `cv::Mat img = cv::imread("rubikscube.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);`.

Comment: First, make sure the image is in the place. If the image is not found these types of errors comes up too. If the image is found then make sure what @rayryeng says

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I run this code on my machine, I get the following error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1) in adaptiveThreshold, file /Users/lakshayg/dev/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp, line 795
```

[`adaptiveThreshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivethreshold#adaptivethreshold) accepts images of type `CV_8UC1` but the one you are passing is `CV_8UC3`.

One way of fixing this would be to read the image as grayscale in the first place.

The [`imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) call with change to

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("rubikscube.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

The `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` here directs the function to read the image as grayscale.

Comment: cv::Mat img = cv::imread("rubikscube.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); This Worked! Thank You.